# Regex extract string between 2 strings, that contains 3rd string

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
(?<=TG00).*?(?=#)
```

which extracts all strings between `TG00` and `#`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/04oqua/1

Now, from above results I want to extract only the string which contains  `TG40 155963`. How can I do it?

Comment: have any preferences to programming languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
TG00[^#]*TG40 155963[^#]*#
```

This pattern just says to find the string `TG40 155963` in between `TG00` and an ending `#`.  For the sample data in your demo there were 3 matches.

### Demo

Comment: Many thanks to all for the answers, all are working great! In my special needs this seems to work smoother. Ty!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex with a lookahead and negated character class:

```
(?<=TG00)(?=[^#]*TG40 155963)[^#]+(?=#)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/04oqua/4)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `(?<=TG00)`: Assert that we have `TG00` at previous position
- `(?=[^#]*TG40 155963)`: Lookahead to assert we have string `TG40 155963` after 0 or more non-# characters, ahead
- `[^#]+`: Match 1+ non-# characters

Comment: You seem to have dropped the `(?=#)` requirement from the end.  I guess it should not match if there isn't actually a `#` after the match.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee, added it now

Answer (score 1):

For some reason appending `.*?` to your lookbehind results in engine error, but works fine with lookahead. Regex below does not match your text *exactly*, but it does extract it via capture group.

```
(?<=TG00).*?(TG40 155963)(?=.*?#)
```